# Clamping 1-inch rope - fastener

Tags: fastener, swing, rope-knots

For a swing suspended from a tree limb by ropes, one side has a little less rope than would be ideal to tie it, so over time it gradually slips out.

It's not a safety hazard like it sounds because it's obvious when it has happened and is in a high visibility area and there's plenty of forewarning, but I'd like to stop having to re-tie it every so often.

I was thinking of getting a rope/cable clamp of some sort but everything I've found seems to be expensive - is there something that is recommended here that would do the trick that would be reasonable?  I don't believe much clamping power is needed given how the situation exhibits.

This is 1 inch thick rope (I think stranded twisted poly but may have the type wrong).

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=youtube+tying+knots&ia=web

Comment: It sure would be nice if you gave us a pic of the current rope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overkill, but that's OK, - made for "wire rope" don't go overboard on tightening or you might damage plastic rope, but these are simple and inexpensive. Should be fine for just keeping a knot from coming loose.

[image: u-bolt rope clip image from uscargocontrol.com]

If the location is near the user, you'll need to tape over the ends so nobody gets cut on the hardware.

On second thought, this might actually work better for the job you describe - plain old stainless steel worm drive hose clamp. Still needs taping over to prevent cuts if in an accessible location.

[image: worm-drive hose clamp image from wholesaleindustrialsupply.com]

Comment: Not sure the hose clamp would work as the fastener itself. Are you suggesting it just to keep the existing knot from slipping loose?

Comment: Wasn't intending *either* to be "the fastener itself" - question reads (to me) as "keep short knot from slipping", not "replace short knot with hardware." If replacing short knot with hardware, might as well buy a longer rope, it will be less expensive than rope hardware rated for supporting humans. **Learning to splice rope** would be another option, but that can also take some length to be secure.

Comment: Fair enough. Of course, ropes for hanging swings _should_, ideally, be long enough to tie secure knots, but, some people like swinging on the edge, I suppose. +1

Comment: Ordered the first one - thanks Ecnerwal.  I didn't go with the second one out of concern it could cut into and weaken the rope over time.